# Super Multicollider Dropdown™ Search

Tags: script

> Spawned by https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/138117/178438

This script adds a search box to the multicollider.

### Installation

- [Click here to install](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/SpecificStuff/ColliderSearch.user.js). Will only work in Chrome or Firefox (the latter requires Greasemonkey).
- [Source](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/SpecificStuff/ColliderSearch.user.js)

### More info

It adds a search which works for all the tabs. Basically, it searches the first line of text, along with the `href` of the first link it encounters.

For the 'hot' tab, it searches by title and site URL.

For the "sites" tab, it searches by site name and/or url. Yseful if you quickly want to go to an SE site and don't like typing.

For the inbox, it searches by post/chatroom name and URL. Useful for finding all your chem.SE inbox items, or all your meta items, etc.

For the notification tab, it just searches notification text This is useful if you want to mask everything but your "badge" notifications(or "edit" notifications).

[image]